# zend framework: set action in form class

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have a Zend Framework application and I am stuck with setting the form action in the form class.

```
class Form_Nieuws_AddForm extends Zend_Form {

    public function init() {
    $this->setMethod('get');
    $this->setAction('/test/blaat');
    $this->setAttribs(array(
        'id' => 'frmCreate',
        'class' => 'baal'
    ));
            ....
    }
}
```

The attribs are set just fine, but the action and method not?
If I move these to the controller it works just fine. How come?

Comment: They are set in `$this->setMethod('get');` and `$this->setAction('/test/blaat');
` respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I where you, I would set the method in the form init method using the Zend_Form costants like this:

```
$this->setMethod(self::METHOD_POST);
```

and the action in the controller using the proper method to costruct the urls:

```
$Form->setAction($this->view->url(array('controller' => 'test', 'action' => 'blaat'), 'default', TRUE));
```

Comment: Is there a way to have the second command in Zend_Form class (perhaps a better place than the controller). By default view is not available there.